# need to have an android app certificates updated from debug to active

Tags: android, debugging, certificate, apk

folks,
I have a semi-complete app, that is stuck in debug mode certificate. I need some help to correct the certificates and make it eligible for the android market. any help would be appreciated.
this is the message i get when I try uploading to market:
Market does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.
Market requires that the certificate used to sign the apk be valid until at least October 22, 2033. Create a new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

This link [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) tells you all the steps you need to take.

Pay attention to the sections **Signing for Public Release** and **Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT.**
Then the only command line actions you need to take are for generating your private key.

Comment: thanks nick, truth is, I am not a developer myself. the person who started this for me took a job and is no longer available to finish up. Is eclipse a software I can download and use as a non-developer. I appreciate your help here.